# Specify a subdirectory in the current folder

Tags: python, file, io

I have text file inside the .py file folder

```
f = open('a.txt',"w")
```

i also have a folder at the .py file directory and i want to open a text file located in that folder

i tried to specify the folder, but it doesn't work

```
f = open('\foldername\a.txt',"w")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have to specify that the path is from the current directory (`.`)

For this you will have to do

```
f = open(r'.\foldername\a.txt',"w")
```

You can use the forward slash `/`

```
f = open(r'./foldername/a.txt',"w")
```

Remember to use a `raw string` to prevent the backslash plague.

Or you can do as @ujjwal has mentioned`open('foldername/a.txt',"w")`

Comment: do i have to use the 'r' when i specify location?

Comment: @YovelZanzuri That is just to prevent the back slash plague. *It is not required* (Though it is a good practise)

Comment: `/` works in windows and linux

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, But why do I see everyone using ` \ ` in Windows? (I've not used windows)

Comment: I don't use windoze either  but probably just because windoze itself uses backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
f = open("foldername/a.txt","w")
f.write('hi there\n')
```

Comment: upvote for showing direct usage. (Will incorporate in my ans)